# p-Variation distance defines semi-martingales

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, rough-paths

**Question**

---

When, does the process $\tilde{X}_t$, defined path-wise by
$$
\tilde{X}_t(\omega)\triangleq \rho_{\frac1{2}}\left((y_t,\mathbb{Y}_t),(x_t(\omega),\mathbb{X}_t(\omega))\right),
$$
define a semi-martingale?  Where the notation is:

**Notation**

---

- $X_t$ is an $\mathbb{R}^d$-valued semi-martingale defined on the filtered probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathcal{F}_t,\mathbb{P})$,
- $(x_t(\omega),\mathbb{X}_t(\omega))$ is a lift of $X_t(\omega)$ to a (random) rough-path of regularity at most $\frac1{2}$,
- $(y_t,\mathbb{Y}_t):[0,T]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d \oplus (\mathbb{R}^d\otimes \mathbb{R}^d)$ is a rough path of Holder continuity atmost $\frac1{2}$.
- $\rho_{\frac1{2}}$ is the $\frac1{2}$-Holder rough path metric.